# How I can make attention to an earlier question I can answer now?

Tags: support

I think I've found a better or probably the correct answer to an earlier question. How  is this answer found by the OP and other users?

Shouldn't it be shown as active now? I couldn't find it yet.

Comment: The OP is always notified.

Comment: O, yes, this will appear in the inbox messages, I see!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you already have your own answer, remember too that you can offer a bounty to bring attention to a question. There are various reasons for offering a bounty: maybe an answer is particularly good and you want to bring attention to it, maybe a question is good but has no answers, or perhaps the current answers aren't sufficient.

It sounds like a bounty might not apply to this current situation, but I still felt it was important information to share.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, yes, now it has appeared in the beta SE as active, when I came back of the beta site. It just was enduring a moment or twos.